# Python how to reduce the number of duplicate elements in a list by half

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to halve the number of duplicate elements in a list.

eg. 
A=[2,3,3,3,4,2,2,6,2]
so, the list show be
A=[2,2,3,3,4,6]

As there are 4 2s in the list it should be halved.

In the case, there is an odd number of entries the result shall be rounded up.

Comment: show what you have done and ask for help only after it.

Comment: @Electrons If an answer has helped you with your question you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to get all of the unique values in the original list. We do this by creating a dictionary with keys based on unique values.

Next, we iterate through the dictionary of keys and sum the number of items in the original list that match the key and set the value accordingly.

Finally, we create a new list by iterating over the dictionary using a range of the value (count of the key) using ceiling division to return an integer result (accounting for 'zero' values by using or 1).

I have provided a test for a list of integers, a list of strings, and a more compact version utilizing comprehensions and a mixed list of integers and strings.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Reduce duplicates in the list to half of the original count.
"""
from math import ceil


def main():
    my_int_list = [2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 6, 2]
    my_str_list = ['two', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'four', 'two', 'two', 'six', 'two']

    # For Python 3.5 and earlier
    from collections import OrderedDict
    unique = OrderedDict.fromkeys(my_int_list)

    # For Python 3.6+
    unique = dict.fromkeys(my_int_list)
    for k, v in unique.items():
        unique[k] = sum(item == k for item in my_int_list)

    # Integer test
    new_int_list = []
    for k, v in unique.items():
        for i in range(0, ceil(v / 2) or 1):
            new_int_list.append(k)

    print(new_int_list)

    # String test
    unique = dict.fromkeys(my_str_list)
    for k, v in unique.items():
        unique[k] = sum(item == k for item in my_str_list)

    new_str_list = []
    for k, v in unique.items():
        for i in range(0, ceil(v / 2) or 1):
            new_str_list.append(k)

    print(new_str_list)

    # Slim Version
    my_multi_list = [2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 6, 2, 'two', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'three', 'four', 'two', 'two', 'six', 'two']
    unique = {k: sum(item == k for item in my_multi_list) for k, v in dict.fromkeys(my_multi_list).items()}
    new_multi_list = [k for k, v in unique.items() for _ in range(0, ceil(v / 2) or 1)]

    print(new_multi_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6]
['two', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'four', 'six']
[2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 'two', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'four', 'six']
```

Comment: THE code works but it omits some elements  If the no. Similar elements is odd.......eg list=[2,2,2,2,2] Then the  reqr list should be list=[2,2,2] it should not omit the extra 2.....plz help me sir

Comment: @Electrons The // operator in Python is used to perform floor division otherwise known as integer division. This means that a // b first divides a by b and gets the integer quotient while discarding the remainder. The result of a//b is always an integer and will always be less than half in this case. If you want to divide in half always rounding up you will need to add in a check for an odd number.

Comment: @Electrons I changed the division to standard and imported the [math.ceil()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) (ceiling) function to ensure the resulting division is always rounded up to the nearest integer.